# How to model mutual friends in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, database

We need to show mutual facebook friends for each listings (Similar to what airbnb does). We dont need to query by friends only show mutual connections for each listing. This would be relatively straightforward in a relational database, but I'm somewhat stuck on the best way to accomplish it in MongoDB. What is the best way to query for mutual friends between the logged in user and the listing owner? Should I query for each listing using a foreach loop individually after querying for listings or is there a way to query for both listings and mutual friends in one go?

The current schema that I have is:

```
Listing: {
   user_id: object id,
   ...
}

User: {
      _id: object id,
      friends: [{facebook_id: string, name: string}]
      ...
}
```

Comment: Have you got a friend schema yet or is that basically your question? It is hard to tell whether you are looking for an advancement on what you have or suggestions on the entire schema

Comment: I have edited the question to add the schema

Comment: Analyzing relationship chains between entities is a use-case where mongoDB is generally bad at. It's the domain of graph databases. When your project isn't very far yet and this is the primary task it is supposed to solve, you should consider to switch to one.

Comment: @Philipp I understand that a graph database is very good for this, but this is just one very small feature and not the main focus of the project. Should I use a graph database just for this feature?

Comment: Any additional technology you add to a project is another point of failure and another area of know-how which is later required to maintain it. Some companies are successful with a heterogenous storage strategy, but these are usually the companies who can afford to hire a specialist for each type of database. I can't help you with this decision without knowing a **lot** more about your project, your team and your company.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, in relational world you would need a simple inner join, right? You do inner join of friends of one user to another, and get mutual friends. This may seem simple, and easy, but under the hood, this is a costly operation and it is not any better than running a custom Map/Reduce in Mongo and get the same data.
Internally operation will be the same: simply intersect to lists of ids. 
Since I'm currently not very good with Map/Reduce, I will not post example. I personally,  would just load friends of both users into memory and intersect there. This should not be much worse, then doing inner join in RDBMS.